# Typescript interfaces that print book info

Tags: typescript

I need create an book library with interfaces that returns string with book data ISBN:Title(pages) similar to this:

```
978-1-55-994633-9:Ulises(847)
```

My code is this:

```
interface Book {
  title: string;
  pages: number;
}
// I can only write code here .... 

interface bookLibrary {
  isbn: "string";
  thebook: Book;
  printInfo: (isbn: string) => void;
}

// ...until here. Without modifying the rest.
let mybookLibrary:bookLibrary = {}

mybookLibrary['978-1-55-994633-9']={
  title:'Ulises',
  pages:847
}
mybookLibrary['978-0-00-715566-8,']={
  title:'The Alchemist',
  pages:124
}
```

I can only modify the booklibrary interface in such a way that when creating a book element the info is printed like this: 978-1-55-994633-9:Ulises(847)

But I can´t get it to work

Answer (score 1):

See [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for reference

```
interface Book {
  title: string;
  pages: number;
}

type BookLibrary = {
  [isbn: string]: Book
}

// declare a separate interface to handle logic there
interface BookController {
  registerBook(isbn: string, book: Book): void;

  printInfo: (isbn: string) => void;
}

// implementation sample
class Controller implements BookController {
  private bookLibrary: BookLibrary = {};

  printInfo(isbn: string): void {
    const book = this.bookLibrary[isbn];
    console.log(`${isbn}:${book.title}(${book.pages})`);
  }

  registerBook(isbn: string, book: Book): void {
    this.bookLibrary[isbn] = book;
  }

}

const controller = new Controller();
controller.registerBook('978-1-55-994633-9', { title: 'Ulises', pages: 847})
controller.printInfo('978-1-55-994633-9');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answr Viktor, but in the exercise it specifies that I can only write code where the interface is without modifying the rest. I can even delete the interface to write something else, but the teacher has given us a hint saying that we have to implement an interface... I have edited the question with a comment to especifies where I can write....

Comment: Ok, I see. Can't find a way to implement it is a setter for a random key, so will look forward for the solution.

Comment: You might have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy though